# List with Delimited Values Performance

Tags: java, database, list, collections, split

I'm pulling a List (ArrayList) of data that represents a single row from a database view. While each column normally has a single value, some columns have a delimited String value, such as this:

```
CompanyID  CompanyName   ContactIDs  Contacts
49         Test Company  5;9         Alice;Bob
```

Currently, I'm pulling a sub-list of the first values, and then parsing the rest with `String.split()`, but I'm worried about performance, especially when I'm loading several hundred of these objects at a time. Here is my method:

```
public void loadFromData(List data) {
    getCompany().load(data.subList(0, 2)); 
    //Pulls 49 and Test Company and loads it into a Company object

    getContacts().clear();
    //getContacts() retrieves an ArrayList of Contact objects
    String[] contactIds = ((String)data.get(2)).split(";");
    String[] contactNames = ((String)data.get(3)).split(";");

    List data = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < companyCategoryIds.length; i++) {
        data.clear();
        data.add(contactIds[i]);
        data.add(getCompany().getCompanyId());
        data.add(contactNames [i]);
        getContacts().add(new Contact().load(data));
    }    
}
```

Is there a better way to go about doing this? Or is this probably the most efficient way to divvy up the List that I'm given?

Assuming that I cannot change the List itself, the joining via ';' is done server-side on the database before I get it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `String.split()` is the most straightforward way, but it does use regex and it can be a bit slow if you do that a lot. However, since you're doing database access (which is a lot slower), I wouldn't worry about it just yet. Run a profiler to see whether you actually have a problem, before trying to get rid of String.split(). Optimization is not something you do just because you *feel* that something is slow.